# App crashes while send / receive ByteArray through socket

Tags: android, sockets, arrays, transfer, datainputstream

I'm trying to make a simple chatting app, using socket communication.
My goal is to send and receive text and images(from smartphone gallery) successfully.
Text part successful, but I'm having trouble with images.

I wrote a code using dataInput/OutputStream, and below is the code, which is establishing socket connection for image transfer, using bytearray(The app use different port for text and image).

```
    class image_connection_thread extends Thread{
    public boolean flag=true;
    public void run(){
        try{
            socket2 = new Socket(Ip,port_img); 
            //Imgage Streams
            img_output= new DataOutputStream(socket2.getOutputStream());
            img_input= new DataInputStream(socket2.getInputStream());
            
            while(flag)
            {   
                ///////////////////
                img_input.readFully(byte_input);
                **//////   This line makes problem(App dies). But no exception message occurs.  ////** 
                
                if(byte_input==null)
                    break;
                image_received=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byte_input, 0, byte_input.length);
                Message Msg = new Message();
                Msg.obj=image_received;
                handler_img.sendMessage(Msg);           
            }
            socket2.close();
            
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            tv_Text.append(e.getMessage()+"connection failed3\n");
        }
    }       
}
```

While loop is to wait for input bytearray from server. Handler displays decoded bytearray on display.

--> img_input.readFully(byte_input); I think this line makes problem. I checked that handler works well, and with empty while block, App didn't die.

What would be the problem?

Server side code is shown below.(message threads are omitted)

```
public class server 
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread thread1=new port1_thread();
    Thread thread2=new port2_thread();
    thread1.start();        
    thread2.start();        
}
}

class port2_thread extends Thread
{
ServerSocket serversocket = null;
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        serversocket = new ServerSocket(9003);
        while(true)
        {
            Socket socket = serversocket.accept();              
            Thread thread= new image_thread(socket);            
            thread.start(); 
        }
        
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("1-2"+e.getMessage());}
}

}


class image_thread extends Thread
{
static ArrayList<DataOutputStream> list2 = new ArrayList<DataOutputStream>();
Socket socket;  
DataOutputStream output2 = null;
    
image_thread(Socket socket)//constructor
{
    this.socket=socket;
    try  //data output stream
    {
         output2 = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
         list2.add(output2);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         System.out.println("22"+e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void run()
{
    try
    {
        //output2= new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream input2=new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        while(true)
        {
            for (DataOutputStream output2 : list2) 
            {
                byte[] b = new byte[1024];  
                input2.readFully(b);
                output2.write(b);
                output2.flush();                
                
            }               
        }
                
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("33"+e.getMessage());}
    
    finally
    {
        list2.remove(output2);
        try
        {
            socket.close();
        }catch(Exception ignored){}
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I see that you try to read data at `input2.readFully(b);` and then send it back on server. But I do not see that you are sending any data on client. Do you send data to server in some other code? Try to comment `input2.readFully(b);` in server code and check.

Comment: @Michal
class image_send_thread extends Thread{
  public void run(){
   try{
    img_output.write(byte_img);
    img_output.flush();     
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
    tv_Text.append(e.getMessage()+"failed2\n");
   }
  }
 }

The code above is clientside code, which is sending bytearray to server.